# Creating new column based on rows of previous column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to assign treatment labels to my experimental ids.  SO has been helpful in getting me this far, but now I'm not sure why my code doesn't work.  The ids are numbers (entered as factors(colname is plotF)) and the treatments are A, B, and C.  The dataframe is very large, this is an example.

```
data$trt[data$plotF == c(12, 21, 35, 43)] <- "A"
data$trt[data$plotF == c(15, 23, 32, 41)] <- "B"
data$trt[data$plotF == c(13, 24, 31, 46)] <- "C"
```

The output is:

```
plotF  trt
21 <NA>
24    C
46 <NA>
12 <NA>
23 <NA>
31 <NA>
13 <NA>
43    A
32 <NA>
15 <NA>
35    A
41    B
24 <NA>
46 <NA>
32    B
31 <NA>
13    C
21    A
12 <NA>
43    A
23 <NA>
15 <NA>
41 <NA>
35 <NA>
```

Why is it working sometimes but not always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens, if you substitute `==` with `%in%` like following?

```
data$trt[data$plotF %in% c(12, 21, 35, 43)] <- "A"
data$trt[data$plotF %in% c(15, 23, 32, 41)] <- "B"
data$trt[data$plotF %in% c(13, 24, 31, 46)] <- "C"
```